# Teamcity Finish Build Trigger is not Firing

Tags: triggers, teamcity, buildconfiguration

I have two builds configured such that one is supposed to trigger another on a successful run.

I have created a Build Config **A**, and a build config **B** that has a Finish Build Trigger linked to build A. Both A and B are very simple test builds having only a single command line build step echoing "Success", so that they will always succeed. Neither of these builds are part of build chains nor do they have any other snapshot dependencies or steps. Build A is finishing successfully but is not triggering Build B. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Finish Build Triggers should be avoided for two reasons: 1) they are confusing (hence this question), 2) they work backwards compared to how TeamCity usually works.

A Finish Build Trigger *triggers* another build. In your example, if you run Build B successfully, the Finish Build Trigger *of Build B* will trigger a new Build A build. To avoid this confusing configuration, I *strongly urge* you to use Snapshot Dependencies whenever possible. A Snapshot Dependency configured in Build B pointing to Build A (that is, you set up a dependency to A from B) will work as you seem to want to configure the builds to work in the above example, that is when you start a Build B, Build A will run first and foremost.